# Self-Join with missing rows on both sides

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing people joining and leaving an organization.

**Sample data**: [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1abeb/5)

```
| pId |     pName |  Unit | YearIn | YearOut |
|-----|-----------|-------|--------|---------|
|   1 |      Noah | North |   2013 |  (null) |
|   2 |      Liam | North |   2013 |    2014 |
|   3 |     Mason | North |   2013 |    2014 |
|   4 |     Jacob | North |   2000 |    2014 |
|   5 |   William |  West |   2000 |    2013 |
|   6 |     Ethan |  West |   2013 |    2013 |
|   7 |   Michael |  West |   2014 |    2015 |
|   8 | Alexander |  West |   2013 |  (null) |
```

For years >= 2013 I want to get the number of entries and leaves, grouped by year and unit.

**Desired output** (I'm unsure if it's easier or harder to include the row where no data exists at all):

```
| Year |  Unit |  NumIn | NumOut |
|------|-------|--------|--------|
| 2013 | North |      3 | (null) |
| 2013 |  West |      2 |      2 |
| 2014 | North | (null) |      3 |
| 2014 |  West |      1 | (null) |
| 2015 | North | (null) | (null) |      (optional)
| 2015 |  West | (null) |      1 |
```

To get NumIn and NumOut in one row, I need some sort of self join, I guess.
**I tried**:

```
SELECT p1.Year, p1.Unit, p1.NumIn, p2.NumOut FROM 
(
    SELECT YearIn AS Year, Unit, COUNT(pId) AS NumIn
    FROM People
    WHERE YearIn >= 2013
    GROUP BY YearIn, Unit
) p1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT YearOut AS Year, Unit, COUNT(pId) AS NumOut
    FROM People
    WHERE YearOut >= 2013
    GROUP BY YearOut, Unit
) p2 
    ON p1.Year = p2.Year AND p1.Unit = p2.Unit
```

but of course that only gives me rows with data on the left side.

```
| Year |  Unit | NumIn | NumOut |
|------|-------|-------|--------|
| 2013 | North |     3 | (null) |
| 2013 |  West |     2 |      2 |
| 2014 |  West |     1 | (null) |
```

---

The result will be input to a pivot table in Excel. So I "cheated" and used a simple UNION query to get all the data:

```
SELECT YearIn AS Year, Unit, COUNT(pId) AS NumIn, NULL AS NumOut
FROM People
WHERE YearIn >= 2013
GROUP BY YearIn, Unit

UNION ALL

SELECT YearOut AS Year, Unit, NULL AS NumIn, COUNT(pId) AS NumOut
FROM People
WHERE YearOut >= 2013
GROUP BY YearOut, Unit

ORDER BY Year, Unit;
```

Result:

```
| Year |  Unit |  NumIn | NumOut |
|------|-------|--------|--------|
| 2013 | North |      3 | (null) |
| 2013 |  West | (null) |      2 |
| 2013 |  West |      2 | (null) |
| 2014 | North | (null) |      3 |
| 2014 |  West |      1 | (null) |
| 2015 |  West | (null) |      1 |
```

This works as basis for a pivot table, but I would like to know how to get the desired result in Sql Server.

I'm using Sql Server 2008 R2 in case it matters.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do a Full Outer Join? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187518(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: omg, why have I never heard of that? Yes, I guess I'm trying to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want a subquery and aggregation:

```
SELECT Year, Unit, SUM(NumIn) as NumIn, SUM(NumOut) as NumOut
FROM (SELECT YearIn AS Year, Unit, COUNT(pId) AS NumIn, NULL AS NumOut
      FROM People
      WHERE YearIn >= 2013
      GROUP BY YearIn, Unit
      UNION ALL
      SELECT YearOut AS Year, Unit, NULL AS NumIn, COUNT(pId) AS NumOut
      FROM People
      WHERE YearOut >= 2013
      GROUP BY YearOut, Unit
     ) yu
GROUP BY Year, Unit;
```

Comment: For readability I prefer this solution. Thank you all, including @cjds for the Full Outer Join hint.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
WITH Years(y) AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES('2013'),('2014'),('2015') ) AS tbl(y)
)
,Units AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Unit FROM People
)
SELECT *
FROM Years CROSS JOIN Units
CROSS APPLY(SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM People AS inP WHERE inP.Unit=Units.Unit AND Years.y=inP.YearIn) AS NumIn
                  ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM People AS outP WHERE outP.Unit=units.Unit AND Years.y=outP.YearOut ) As NumOut
) AS Counts
ORDER BY Years.y,Unit
```

Comment: Whoa, interesting. Gives me several new concepts to read about... and the "empty" row too. Can you give me a link or keyword what the `Years(y)` syntax means (or what it's called)?