# MS Access JOIN columns from two tables - NOT UNION

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I need to write a query in MS Access to get a count of operation by 2 dates column. Structure of my table is

| start_date | end_date | f1 | f2 | f3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-05 | f1 | f2 | f3 |
| 2022-11-15 | 2022-12-07 | f1 | f2 | f3 |
| 2022-12-06 | 2022-12-07 | f1 | f2 | f3 |
| 2022-11-15 | 2022-12-06 | f1 | f2 | f3 |

I need output as for all dates of a month

| date | Total start_date on date | Total end_date on date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-15 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-12-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 2022-12-05 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-12-06 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-12-07 | 0 | 2 |

What I have done is (which is incorrect, since it is possible on a given start_date, the count is zero and for some end_date count is zero)

```
SELECT start_date, count(start_date) as startcount, tbl2.endcount FROM tbl
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT end_date, count(end_date) as endcount FROM tbl GROUP BY end_date) as tbl2
ON start_date=tbl2.end_date
GROUP BY start_date
ORDER BY start_date
```

Any suggestions?

I have already checked for the existing [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615177/how-do-i-write-a-full-outer-join-query-in-access), but they do not match the requirements, since in other answers they are doing a UNION of result, which is not my question.

Comment: To get your question reopened, please provide sample data and expected result. [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Sure. I have added sample input and expected output.

Comment: ... sample data *in table format*. :-o  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables

Comment: Apologies. Thanks for the pointers. Made it readable in tabular format.

Comment: The sample data has no record with end_date = 2022-12-06, I guess you are missing a row there?

Comment: And: I don't see why the linked duplicate doesn't apply. Access has no `FULL OUTER JOIN`, so your SQL cannot work. It must be simulated with a UNION query. But this UNION query should give you the desired result.

Comment: How would a UNION add total_end_date column to the result? One query can give me result of total_start_date, but merging with the next column is the challenge hence different from the linked duplicate question.

Comment: You need to GROUP BY and COUNT separately for both columns, providing 0 as value for the other column. You can UNION both cases, and then SUM over the results to merge the rows where dates exists in both columns - this is quite similar to a question I asked, see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274957/3820271

Comment: Or you can treat the special case separately, with a 3rd subquery using INNER JOIN. Then UNION ALL the 3 results. This is the 2nd approach in the top answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize that only one vote was needed to reopen and answer...
I wrote most in the comments, but the first approach would look like this:

```
SELECT TheDate, SUM(startcount) AS TotalStart, SUM(endcount) AS TotalEnd
FROM (
    SELECT start_date as TheDate, count(*) as startcount, 0 AS endcount 
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY start_date
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT end_date as TheDate, 0 as startcount, count(*) as endcount 
    FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY end_date
)
GROUP BY TheDate
```

And JJ32 is correct, this can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT TheDate, SUM(startcount) AS TotalStart, SUM(endcount) AS TotalEnd
FROM (
    SELECT start_date as TheDate, 1 as startcount, 0 AS endcount 
    FROM tbl
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT end_date as TheDate, 0 as startcount, 1 as endcount 
    FROM tbl 
)
GROUP BY TheDate
```

This is basically an UNPIVOT operation.

Comment: This works even without grouping in the inner select. Just 1 as startcount/1 as endcount wil suffice.

Comment: This doesn't handle the last row of my output. (2022-12-07  0  2)

Comment: @Sawan Did you use UNION ALL and not UNION? Please show the results in your question if it does not work.

Comment: @Sawan: it does for me, using your test data (without columns f1..f3, they don't seem to play any role). Using count(*) is better, but both versions worked for me.